# Is it possible to use the VLC plugin right in firefox when playing Youtube videos?

Tags: firefox, vlc-media-player, youtube

I have a plugin (called Open With) which allows me to right-click and open a Youtube video in VLC. Is it possible to immediately use the VLC plugin in-place (where the video would normally be) in Youtube, rather than try to play it with their player?